# mongoose: Removing subdocument's content

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose (using current version) schema with a subdocument:

```
var mySchema = new Schema({
  subdocument: { property1: { type: String } }
});
var myModel = mongoose.model('My-Model', mySchema);
```

Now I'm trying to update an existing document and to remove the `subdocument` like so using `doc.subdocument = {}`:

```
new myModel({ name: 'test', subdocument: { property1: 'test' }}).save(function(err, doc) {
  console.log('saved doc:\n', doc);
  doc.subdocument = {}; // remove content of subdocument
  doc.save(function(err, doc) {
    console.log('updated doc:\n', doc); // subdocument: null
    myModel.findById(doc._id, function(err, doc) {
      console.log('retrieved doc:\n', doc); // subdocument: { property1: 'test' }
      mongoose.disconnect();
    });
  });
});
```

The callback in `doc.save` returns the document with `subdocument: null`, so I assumed, the update worked as expected. However, when examining the database, the `subdocument`'s content is still there -- this can be seen by above's sample code when I retrieve the document again.

The document in the DB looks as:

```
{ subdocument: { property1: 'test' }, __v: 0, _id: 57593a8130f2f7b6a12886b1 }
```

Is this a bug or a fundamental misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that regular JS object properties in schema are given a [`Mixed`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed) schema type by Mongoose.

For these types of properties, if they change, you need to explicitly tell Mongoose about that change before saving:

```
doc.subdocument = {};
doc.markModified('subdocument');
doc.save(...);
```

The "updated doc" will *not* reflect the document as it's stored in the database, only how it's represented in memory (it's simply another reference to the `doc` object).

As an alternative to `.save()`, you can also use [`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate), with the added advantage that you can make it return the updated (stored-in-the-database) document using the `new` option:

```
myModel.findByIdAndUpdate(doc._id, {
  $set : { subdocument : {} }
}, { new : true }, function(err, doc) {
  // `doc` will now reflect what's stored in the database
});
```

Comment: Thank you, `markModified` does the trick! And especially thanks about the note of the returned `doc` document. Until now I had naively assumed that this was the document as stored in the database, so I'll have to review my code carefully.

Comment: @qqilihq see my edit, I added an alternative to `save` that might be useful as well.